# Workspace configuration consistency check is disabled. In Eclipse Websphere Application

Tags: java, websphere, production

I am struggling to get my web application to run locally on my machine. I have done all the configs but every time I restart my server I get,
"Workspace configuration consistency check is disabled." And I am unable to access the web app locally. Here is a portion of the log,

```
[2/18/21 11:00:37:883 EST] 0000006a WorkSpaceMana A   WKSP0500I: Workspace configuration consistency check is disabled.
[2/18/21 11:05:16:210 EST] 000000c0 WebContainer  E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.internal.WebContainer handleRequest SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle / has not been defined.
[2/18/21 11:10:16:118 EST] 000000c0 WebContainer  E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.internal.WebContainer handleRequest SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle / has not been defined.
```

If someone could please assist me with a zoom meeting or if they could please suggest a fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The "I" at the end of the WKSP0500I message tells you that it's just an informational message and you can ignore it in this case.  The SRVE0255E is an error and is telling you that you haven't configured the server the expose your webapp properly.  Have a look at the steps to diagnose in this [IBM support doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-diagnose-error-srve0255e-webgroupvirtual-host-handle-0-has-not-been-defined) .